# Why does syslogd-ng print items in square brackets twice

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

I'm using syslogd-ng and have noticed that the command:
logger [test] message

results in the following log message:
Sep 17 15:39:09 Test: [test] [test] message

where the priority has been removed. Why does adding the square brackets around the word test do this?